# Find tangent point on circle with external point

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

> Given this image where we know P, O and the radius of the circle in 2D, how to find T?
>
> [image]
>
> (PMN is irrelevant to the problem)

There is an item rotating in 2D along the circle, when it reaches T, it should leave the circle and move along the red line (similar to the disc throwing concept).

I feel I should be using the law of sines and SOHCAHTOA but I fail to get a 2D point value for T.

EDIT: I'm thinking that since I know the length of PO and the radius of the circle on which the tangent should be placed, I can do:

```
alpha = sin(^-1)(r / PO) 
theta = 180 - 90 - alpha
norm = PO / |PO|
v = norm.Rotate(theta)
v * r
```

`alpha` is the angle at $P$ and `theta` is the angle at $O$.

I should be able to normalize $PO$, rotate by `theta` and multiply by `r`. (Since this is meant to happen in a 3D engine, I have access to quaternion and transform methods).

Though this feel like a long path for something I may be able to find out with trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pythagoras theory we know that
$$
\overline{PT} = \sqrt{\overline{P0}^2 - \overline{0T}^2}
$$
Hence, we can find the point $T$ by calculatin the intersect between two circles,
$$
x = \frac{d^2 - r^2 + R^2}{2d}
$$
[image]

Comment: So it turned out I needed to look into two circle intersection. I'd say your answer was helpful but not quite just it. I ended up on this page with the code I need. Thanks as you did lead me in the right direction.